# Algebras for the induced monad on presheaves

Tags: ct.category-theory

$\require{AMScd}$Let $\cal A$ be a $\cal V$-category, and consider the diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
{\cal A} @>y>> [{\cal A}^°, {\cal V}]\\
@VTVV @VV\hat TV\\
{\cal A} @>>y> [{\cal A}^°, {\cal V}]
\end{CD}
$$
where $\hat T$ is the Yoneda extension of the functor $yT$ and $T$ is a $\cal V$-monad on $\cal A$. Then, $T$-algebras embed in $\hat T$-algebras via Yoneda, meaning that $\hat T$-algebra has underlying object a representable if and only if it is of the form $(ya : yTA\to yA)$ for some $T$-algebra $a\colon TA\to A$.

> But how bigger are $\hat T$-algebras in general? As a subcategory of ${\hat T}\text{-Alg}$, does $T\text{-Alg}$ have interesting generation properties?

I am interested in a really specific case:

1. ${\cal A}$ is a small subcategory of $\bf Cat$ (a category of diagrams in the sense of [[Gro, 4.21]](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/groth_derivators.pdf)), and $\cal V$ is the category of possibly large, but locally small categories $\bf CAT$. So now $y$ sends a category into its represented prederivator.
2. $T$ is the monad induced by cotensoring with a comonoid ${\cal C}$, i.e. $T\colon J \mapsto J^{\cal C}$ with obvious induced structure maps, so that $\hat T$ sends $\mathbb D$ to $J\mapsto\mathbb{D}^{\cal C}(J)=\mathbb{D}(J\times {\cal C})$ (the *shifted* derivator).